# pod install firebase : curl error Failed to connect to dl.google.com port 443

Tags: ios, macos, curl, cocoapods, capacitor

Using capacitor with google Firebase pods for iOS app.

After running "npx cap sync ios", which runs "pod install",
curl seems unable to fetch the file, but it's totally accessible via a web browser for example.

The full log:

```
Ignoring digest-crc-0.6.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine digest-crc --version 0.6.4
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.8.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.8.2
Analyzing dependencies
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
Downloading dependencies
Installing CapacitorFirebaseMessaging (5.1.0)
Installing Firebase 10.8.0 (was 10.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 10.8.0 (was 10.3.0)

[!] Error installing FirebaseAnalytics
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/sc/sc9p75ss0knbrz50f4bhrlmw0000gn/T/d20231002-10058-nn2nbg/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/analytics/5f0d532a0eb9e9ca/FirebaseAnalytics-10.8.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.13.0 cocoapods-downloader/1.6.3'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to dl.google.com port 443 after 18 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I tried updating cocoapod (I have version 1.13.0). I'm using latest version of capacitor 5.
Also using latest version of @capacitor-firebase/messaging

Comment: Did you find any solution?